# Переход на другую версию Visual Studio, INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Добрый день, пользовался VS2016. Сейчас решил перейти на версию 2013, открыл проект на 2013 версии, мне начало выдавать ошибки при работе с INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedItemInListView)));
```

Ругается на nameof:

```
Error   1   The name 'nameof' does not exist in the current context D:\WpfApplication7\WpfApplication7\CreateGroup.xaml.cs  47  68  WpfApplication7
```

В чем может быть проблема? Версию .NET установил так же как и на прошлой студии (4.6.1)

Свойство целиком:

```
public Item SelectedItemInListBox
    {
        get { return _SelectedItemInListBox; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedItemInListBox = value;
            //сообщаем о том, что элемент изменился
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedItemInListBox)));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`nameof` это фича C#6. Visual Studio 2013 поддерживает версии до C#5 включительно. Компилятор просто не понимает, что это за слово.

Comment: Реально доустановить в 2013 версию c#6? Если нет то чем можно это заменить? Этим интерфейсом пользуюсь копипастом, поэтому сам придумать ничего не могу

Comment: @Дмитрий Пишите просто строку "SelectedItemInListBox" (с кавычками)

Comment: @Дмитрий, _Реально доустановить в 2013 версию c#6?_ - нет, к сожалению нет. Я как то тоже задавался этим вопросом. Можете посмотреть варианты решений на [соседнем форуме](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093908/how-to-enable-c-sharp-6-0-feature-in-visual-studio-2013), но, лично мне, они не помогли.

Comment: Спасибо, понял. Пошел устанавливать 2015 :) Может быть кто-то сталкивался с тем что в DataSource(Server Explorer) не появляется пункт MySQL Databases после установки Mysql for Visual studio? Собственно из-за этого и пытался перейти на VS2013, там оно работает.

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение к [ответу @Ruslan Artamonov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/626487/10105), в C# 5 имеет смысл использовать такую магию:

```
protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Имея этот метод в вашем классе (или его базовом классе), вы можете писать просто

```
public Item SelectedItemInListBox
{
    get { return _SelectedItemInListBox; }
    set { _SelectedItemInListBox = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
}
```

или лучше

```
public Item SelectedItemInListBox
{
    get { return _SelectedItemInListBox; }
    set
    {
        if (_SelectedItemInListBox == value)
            return;
        _SelectedItemInListBox = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Таким образом вам не нужно упоминать точное имя свойства вовсе, оно установится самостоятельно через магию `[CallerMemberName]`.

---

Возможно, имеет смысл ещё сократить ваш код, и создать общий базовый класс для всех VM-классов:

```
class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value,
                         [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            return false;

        field = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Имея такой базовый класс, вы можете писать так:

```
class MyListVM : VM
{
    Item _SelectedItemInListBox;
    public Item SelectedItemInListBox
    {
        get { return _SelectedItemInListBox; }
        set { Set(ref _SelectedItemInListBox, value); }
    }
}
```

---

Кстати, для C# 6 (Visual Studio 2015 и старше) можно использовать тот же трюк с более компактной записью:

```
protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
```

Comment: У меня именно так это и записано, по-моему вы мне этот код и давали.

Answer (score 0):

Начиная с 3 версии C# можно использовать также и [Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654263.aspx)

```
    protected void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr)
    {
        var member = (MemberExpression)expr.Body;
        var handler = Volatile.Read(ref PropertyChanged);

        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(member.Member.Name));
    }
```