# Изменение цвета View из ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Как изменить цвет View из ViewModel.

Пробовал реализовать через Color, Brush и SolidBrush. Но вьюшка не отвечает.
Когда попробовал реализовать через string все заработало.

```
public string Colors { get; set; }
```

В конструкторе устанавливаю цвет

```
Colors = Color.AliceBlue.Name.ToString();
```

Тогда все работает.
Неужели это единственный выход? Можно ли это реализовать "более красиво" без string?

Comment: А вы при изменении Color, Brush или SolidBrush оповещали View об изменении?(реализуя INPC вызывает OnPropertyChanged(Имя свойства))

Comment: И как вы обращаетесь из View(код в студию в варианте, когда не работало) и ViewModel код тоже(когда не работало)

Comment: INPC реализую, все работает как положено.
Вопрос только как передавать значение.

Comment: Фишка ещё в том, что цвета в Colors не того типа, который принимают контроля, поэтому это не работает. Вам нужно этот Color обернуть в SolidColorBrush. Через часик дополню ответ, как до дома доберусь.

Comment: @Андрей: я пробовал SolidColorBrush SolBr = new SolidColorBrush(Color.Red), и привязаться к SolBr, но результата не было.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, ваш VM-класс должен реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Тогда изменения в VM будут подхватываться и во View.

Затем, вы не показываете ваш код, а значит, не исключена ошибка в привязке. Перепроверьте!

Ну и наконец, с точки зрения MVVM установка цвета — не задача VM, VM не должна заниматься визуальными свойствами. Найдите *семантику*, смысл, который стоит за сменой цвета, и выставьте как свойство её. А цвет из ней получайте через триггер или конвертер.

---

Пример с триггерами (используем базовый класс `VM` [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/626514/10105)):

```
class SignalVM : VM // реализует INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool haveSignal;
    public bool HaveSignal
    {
        get => haveSignal;
        set => Set(ref haveSignal, value);
    }
}
```

Разметка:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HaveSignal}">
                    <DataTrigger.Value>
                        <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
                    </DataTrigger.Value>
                    <DataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger.Setters>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
</Grid>
```

Вам понадобится объявить `xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`. Вместо `Grid` можно взять, понятно, любой другой элемент.

Comment: а каким образом это реализовать? Можно пример, так как часто сталкиваюсь с такими нюансами(отображение компонента, изменение цвета), но всегда приходится реализовывать это в ВМ.

Comment: дело не в привязке, там все работает.
Вопрос только в том, как передавать.

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: Ну, через конвертер или триггер. Зависит от того, что и как выставляет VM.

Comment: вы часто помогаете с решением, и в других темах видел много полезного от вас про MVVM. Не могли бы показать, как это реализовать "правильно" не нарушая концепцию.
Вот например мне нужно, что бы цвет менялся (оповещал пользователя) если происходит изменение значения сигнала с true на false, и наоборт.

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: почитайте уже про конвертеры, если что-то не понятно - задавайте другой вопрос. Делая за вас всё, мы вам на самом деле не поможем обучиться.

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: Обновил ответ, смотрите.

Comment: @VladD, сегодня писал разметку с использованием примерно такого же DataTrigger'а, реализовал такое расширение: `class FalseExtension : MarkupExtension { public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => false; }`, тогда привязка: `<DataTrigger Binding="..." Value="{ex:False}">` Еще можно сделать что-то такое: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31993746/6766879

Comment: @Андрей: Ага, видел такое вот тут: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29381103/276994

Answer (score 3):

> Можно ли это реализовать "более красиво" без string?

Можно. Вы не должны устанавливать цвета из VM, это задача представления.

Например. У вас чат, вы хотите выделить входящие сообщения голубым, а исходящие - зеленым цветом, вы не должны в VM определять свойство цвет и устанавливать его. Вы должны просто выставить свойство `Direction`, которое будет иметь некий ваш тип, или может `enum`, или, на худой конец, `bool`. А в V вы просто привязываетесь к этому свойству и преобразовываете его в цвет с помощью конвертера:

```
enum Direction { Incoming, Outgoing }

class MainVM : Vm
{
    Direction direction;
    public Direction Direction
    {
        get => direction;
        set => Set(ref direction, value);
    }
}
```

Я использую такую базу для конвертера, она позволяет упростить написание конвертеров и разметку:

```
abstract class ConverterBase : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public abstract object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture);
    public virtual object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => this;
}
```

Сам конвертер, может выглядеть как-то так:

```
class MessageDirectionToBrushConverter : ConverterBase
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var direction = (Direction)value;
        var color = direction == Direction.Incoming
                  ? Colors.LightBlue
                  : Colors.LightGreen;
        return new SolidColorBrush(color);
    }
}
```

Если такой конвертер потребуется в нескольких местах - его можно параметризировать.

Использование:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding Direction,
    Converter={local:MessageDirectionToBrushConverter}}"/>
```

Обратите внимание, конвертер возвращает значение типа `SolidColorBrush` (которое наследуется от `Brush`), а не `Color`, так как заливка элементов задается именно кистью. Как раз именно по этому не работает ваш код (если опустить корректность использования паттерна MVVM).

Comment: Спасибо, буду ждать, займусь пока другими задачами.

Comment: @UporotayaPanda, добавил код