# Привязать цвет к значению переменной

Tags: c#, wpf

есть например такой элемент:

```
<Ellipse Name="indicator"
    Fill="#FFFF2424" 
    Stroke="Black" 
    Width="15"
    Height="15"
    Margin="10,0,0,0"
    />
```

в коде переменная `running=true/false`

как привязать цвет fill эллипса чтобы он был красным при false и зеленым при true?

Comment: `DataTrigger` или конвертер

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Изменение цвета View из ViewModel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/748693/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-view-%d0%b8%d0%b7-viewmodel)