# Как поменять цвет шрифта в строке ListBox-а, содержащего определенное слово

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть список `<ListBox Name="performedPersons" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PersonsPerf}">`.
Связан со списком `List<string> PersonsPerf { get; set; }`.
Нужно сменить цвет шрифта в строке если он содержит слово "Выполнено".
Как это лучше сделать, желательно с помощью MVVM.
Пробовал делать через триггеры

```
<TextBlock.Style>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TextInput}" Value="Выполнено">
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="Green"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TextBlock.Style>
```

Но не нашел свойства которое бы определяло содержание слова "Выполнено".

Пробовал через событие "SizeChanged" у `ListBox`-а, работает, красит слова в синий цвет, но это событие срабатывает только при первой загрузке данных в `ListBox`, а потом, уже цвет становиться снова черный во всех строках.

```
private void performedPersons_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (performedPersons.Items.Count != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < performedPersons.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            string lbxItem = (string)performedPersons.Items[i];
                if (lbxItem.Contains("В процессе"))
                {
                    ListBoxItem lbi = (ListBoxItem)performedPersons.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
                    lbi.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;
                }
        }                                
    }
}
```

Comment: Т.е. вам нужно не полное совпадение, а чтобы текст *содержал* "выполнено"? Почему бы не сделать в VM флаг выполненности? Иначе придется писать конвертер.

Comment: Да, неполное совпадение. Флаг то могу сделать, только каким образом его использовать?  <br/>  Сейчас каждая строка `ListBox`-а представляет собой имя и статус `%name% - %status%`. И не понятно как его совмещать с флагом, создать новый список с флагами?

Comment: Ну как, тем же DataTrigger, примерно как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/748702/218063

Answer (score 2):

Большое спасибо [Андрей NOP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218063/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9-nop) за помощь!
Решение следующее:
View

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="1" Name="performedPersons" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PersonsPerf}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
...
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" x:Name="namePerf" Text="{Binding Path=Name}">
<TextBlock.Style>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}">
                <DataTrigger.Value>
                    <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
                </DataTrigger.Value>
                <DataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                </DataTrigger.Setters>
            </DataTrigger>                                                                
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

И создал новый класс в модели:

```
public class PersonsPerformer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 Status { get; set; }
}
```

А во ViewModel просто заполнял список нужными данными:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<Person, int> entry in selectedTask)
{
    PersonsPerf.Add(new PersonsPerformer
    {
        Name = entry.Key.Name,
        Status = entry.Value
    });
}
```