# Расположение объекта за пределами Grid

Tags: wpf, xaml

Разрабатываю приложение, в котором нужно сделать некое окно, оно должно:

- Быть всегда посередине приложения.
- Изменять размер при изменении размера самого Window.
- Иметь контент.
- Иметь изображение сбоку, которое, в свою очередь, должно:

  - Привязаться четко к левой части окна за центр (то есть центр изображения должен всегда находиться в начале окна).
  - Изменять размер вместе с окном.

Что я имею ввиду:

[image: project]

Как видим, по центру есть "окошко", оно четко по центру, меняет размер, все как положено. Слева есть эльфийка, которая должна быть всегда в этом месте и изменять размер вместе с самим окном. И тут возникает проблема (даже проблемы)...

1. Эльфийка двигается при изменении размера приложения. Что бы я не делал, вечно прихожу к такому результату (заезжает на окно) и "приколоть" ее к нужной точке без указания точных размеров не получается:

[image: Resize]

2. Для получения такого результата пришлось указать `Margin="-160 0 0 0"`, что не есть хорошо...

Текущий вариант:

```
<!--#region Основная сетка с затенением-->
    <Grid Background="#81000000">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="4*" MaxHeight="550"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MaxWidth="450"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!--#region Рамка/Цвет/Тень-->
            <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="{StaticResource Color.Main.Brush}" 
                    CornerRadius="5"
                    BorderThickness="0 .7 0 .7" 
                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource Color.Line.Horizontal.GradientBrush}">
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="1" Direction="-90" />
                </Border.Effect>
            </Border>
            <!--#endregion-->
            <Grid Column="1">
                <!--#region Контент-->
                <Grid>
                    <!-- /// -->
                </Grid>
                <!--#endregion-->
            </Grid>
            <!--#region Изображение-->
            <Image Grid.Column="0"
                   Source="../../Resources/cha_elf.png"
                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                   Margin="-160 0 0 0"/>
            <!--#endregion-->
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
<!--#endregion-->
```

Пробовал `StackPanel`, `DockPanel`, `Grid` (все в 1 ячейке и сдвигать объект, не двигался, разбить по колонкам - текущий результат), все безрезультатно...

**Собственно вопрос:** Как грамотно "указать эльфийке" место?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Размещайте картинку в отдельном `Grid`, а не в том же самом, где у вас рамка:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="Gray" 
                CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="0,.7" BorderBrush="Black">
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="1" Direction="-90" />
            </Border.Effect>
            <Button Content="Click me" Click="Button_Click" Padding="10,2"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
    <Grid IsHitTestVisible="False">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
               Source="elf.png"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема будет возникать лишь когда ширина окна будет достигать величин меньших чем N * высота окна, где N зависит от пропорций картинки и пропорций строк/столбцов грида — картинка начнет уменьшаться по высоте, а рамка оставаться такой же:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решение здесь зависит от того, какое поведение вы предпочтете больше: либо мы начинаем обрезать картинку (сверху и/или снизу), либо, что я вижу более приемлемым, мы запрещаем величине `ширинаОкна / высотаОкна` достигать значений меньших, чем (вышеупомянутое) `N`, это можно сделать с помощью конвертера масштаба:

```
class ScaleConverter : ConverterBase
{
    public double Scale { get; set; }

    public ScaleConverter(double scale)
        => Scale = scale;

    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => (double)value * Scale;
}
```

и в окне:

```
<Window ...
        MinWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
            Path=ActualHeight, Converter={c:ScaleConverter 0.66}}">
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мм, любопытный подход к конвертерам, возьму на вооружение. Вроде теперь все как надо. Спасибо! Только одного не пойму, почему Scale = 0.66?

Comment: *N зависит от пропорций картинки и пропорций строк/столбцов грида* — я установил высоту 300 и плавно уменьшал ширину окна до того момента, пока картинка не начала уменьшать высоту, получилось ~198, итого 198/300=0,66. У вас будут другие значения, лучше оставить небольшой запас на случай разного отображения у разных пользователей на разных ОС

Comment: `ConverterBase` можете взять здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/748699/218063

Comment: Да, я уже нашел его, спасибо)

Comment: Расширения разметки — наше всё для сокращения ее размеров :)

Comment: О да, тут я полностью согласен. Стандартный вариант весьма не удобный, а этот... прям удивлен, что так можно))

Comment: Можете взять на вооружение некоторые примеры с расширениями разметки: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A218063+*MarkupExtension*)

Comment: Хм, спасибо, погляжу на досуге.