# WPF Реализация условий, соблюдая паттерн MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, условия

Подскажите как реализовать в WPF приложении условия. Например, я хочу, чтобы в зависимости от текста одного TextBlock'a изменялся цвет текста другого текстблока, при этом соблюдая MVVM. Мой вопрос относится не только к данном примеру, а к тому, как в целом менять что-то, при выполнении определенного условия. Подскажите как эти условия задать и как их применить к определенному элементу.

Comment: В самом простом варианте — в сеттере свойства. А к свойствам уже делаете привязки + при необходимости с конвертерами и триггерами

Comment: Вообще вопрос слишком общий и расплывчатый, приводите конкретную проблему, пример

Comment: @АндрейNOP а как мне в триггере прописать событие сходства с тем текстом, который я хочу? Пример: есть ListBox с элементами, в котороых есть некоторые строки. Среди этих строк есть строка, в которой написано installed или Not installed. В зависимости от того, что там написано должен меняться цвет этой строки: если Installed, то зеленый, если not installed, то красный. Что-то типа того, простите, если объясняю непонятно

Comment: Скорее всего это не должно быть текстом, а должно быть отдельным свойством `bool IsInstalled`. Но пока ничего не понятно.

Comment: @АндрейNOP пусть будет так, но все равно как тогда изменить цвет строки? Как я уже сказал, мне важно именно изменить цвет строки в зависимости от install или not install

Comment: Посмотрите этот топик, например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/748693/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP я дико извиняюсь, тут же вопрос из-за моей тупости. Похоже это именно то, что мне нужно, но только как теперь это свойство заставить давать какой-либо результат?
    private bool haveSignal;
        public bool HaveSignal
        {
            get => haveSignal;
            set => Set(ref haveSignal, value);
        }

Comment: У вас должна быть какая-то логика, которая будет ставить или сбрасывать этот флаг, например, в сеттере какого-то другого свойства, как я написал вам в первом комментарии

Comment: @АндрейNOP мне уже стыдно у вас что-либо спрашивать, но если вам не трудно, объясните пожалуйста как через сеттер задать этому свойству какое-либо значение?

Comment: `set { if (Set(ref myProp1, value)) MyProp2 = newValue; }`

Comment: @АндрейNOP ладно, спасибо большое за помощь

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создаем ViewModel с текстовым полем

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _viewModelText;

    public string ViewModelText
    {
        get => _viewModelText;
        set
        {
            if (value == _viewModelText) return;
            _viewModelText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Пишем конвертер из строки в цвет

```
public class StringToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var str = value as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        var colors = typeof(Colors).GetProperties().ToDictionary(pi => pi.Name, co => (Color)co.GetValue(null));
        if (colors.ContainsKey(str)) return new SolidColorBrush(colors[str]);
        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Создаем окно с текстовым полем и биндим на модель

```
<Window x:Class="RU_986676.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RU_986676"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:StringToBrushConverter x:Key="StringToBrushConverter"></local:StringToBrushConverter>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Background="{Binding ViewModelText, Converter={StaticResource StringToBrushConverter}}">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ViewModelText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="300" Height="40"></TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Запускаем всю эту радость

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все исходники ищите [тут](https://github.com/tym32167/SO_Samples/tree/master/src/RU_986676)