# Как создать плиточное меню WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Есть страница разделенная Grid'ом. Нужно в одну ячейку поместить динамически созданные элементы управления (кнопки в виде плиток), причем используя условие.
Если сomboBox.SelectedItem = ... , то создать определенное количество элементов.
Если значение сomboBox.SelectedItem изменилось, то удалить элементы управления, и создать новые. Количество зависит от того, что будет выбрано в comboBox.

Как пример, вот такое меню:

[image: Как пример вот такое меню]

Comment: MVVM используете?

Comment: @VladD, нет. Я пытаюсь понять как сделать. Любая подсказка будет в помощь

Comment: А где ваш комбобокс на скриншоте?

Comment: @VladD, это пример. ComboBox у меня используется для типа товара, т.е. в нем выбрал яблоки и в плиточном меню должны отобразиться сорта яблок для продажи, например.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Окей, смотрите, что должно быть.

Для начала, VM. Допустим, у нас есть список яблок и список груш.

```
enum ProductType
{
    Apples, Pears
}
```

Нам нужна коллекция всех продуктов:

```
public static IEnumerable<ProductType> AllProductTypes { get; } =
    Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProductType)).Cast<ProductType>();
```

И свойство с `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
private ProductType currentProduct;
public ProductType CurrentProduct
{
    get => currentProduct;
    set => Set(ref currentProduct, value);
}
```

(я пользуюсь базовым классом [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/626514/10105)).

Это мы привяжем к комбобоксу:

```
<Combobox ItemsSource="{x:Static local:YourVM.AllProductTypes}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentProduct}"/>
```

Теперь, список. Пускай у нас есть список сортов яблок и список сортов груш.

```
class Product { }
class AppleVariety : Product { }
class PearVariety : Product { }

IEnumerable<Product> AllProducts = ...;
IEnumerable<AppleVariety> AllApples = AllProducts.OfType<AppleVariety>().ToList();
IEnumerable<PearVariety> AllPears = AllProducts.OfType<PearVariety>().ToList();
```

Теперь, нам нужно свойство, представляющее собой текущий список — яблоки или груши.

```
IEnumerable<Product> currentSelection;
IEnumerable<Product> CurrentSelection
{
    get => currentSelection;
    set => Set(ref currentSelection, value);
}
```

Затем, нам нужно при изменении значения `CurrentProduct` менять и список. Сделаем это в сеттере `CurrentProduct`: вместо

```
    set => Set(ref currentProduct, value);
```

напишем там

```
    set => if (Set(ref currentProduct, value)) CurrentSelection = GetCurrentProductList();
```

и соответственно

```
IEnumerable<product> GetCurrentProductList()
{
    switch (CurrentProduct)
    {
    case Apples:
        return AllApples;
    case Pears:
        return AllPears;
    default:
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown product kind");
    }
}
```

Отлично, теперь отображение.

Тут всё просто. Список продуктов показываем так:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentSelection}>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="3"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- тут код для отображения вашего продукта -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Вот вроде бы и всё.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду разбираться

Comment: @ValeryMelnikov: Пожалуйста! Буду рад, если поможет!