# динамическое создание элементов Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем привет! Не могу понять как создать "динамические элементы". 
Предположим что пользователь нажимая на кнопку, создаёт 2 textBox вводит в них значения, ещё раз нажимает, создаёт ещё 2 и аналогичная ситуация. После всех манипуляций нажимает на кнопку "сохранить", и все значения из всех этих текстбоксов мы записываем в файл, допустим такой формат:

```
[[TextBox1: Привет, TextBox2: Пока], [TextBox1: Удачи, TextBox2: Миша]]
```

.
Не понимаю как сделает такое.

Comment: Насчёт `создаёт 2 textBox` обычно либо а) число этих текстбоксов известная во время компиляции константа и их можно заранее налепить на форму и тогда "создать" будет означать "сделать видимыми" либо б) честное динамическое создание, когда координаты прибавляют высоту кнопки и небольшой отступ. Кажется подобных ответов тоже полно на stackoverflow, искали?

Comment: Таки штуки [проще в WPF вытворять](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219057/373567). А здесь [вам нужна коллекция юзерконтролов и панель](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32759588/12888024). Что касается записи в файл, есть такая штука как JSON или XML, например вы можете коллекцию данных для контролов серализовать одной строчкой кода `File.WriteAllText("file.txt", JsonSerializer.Serialize(MyItems));` - [Как сериализировать и десериализировать JSON в .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для наглядности сделал пример на создание одного нового TextBox.

Каждому добавляемому на форму элементу нужно задавать координаты, чтобы они не загораживали друг друга. Следующий элемент должен быть смещен относительно последнего вставленного.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static List<TextBox> TextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox newTextBox = new TextBox();
            TextBox lastOldTextBox = TextBoxes.LastOrDefault();
            if (lastOldTextBox == null)
            {
                newTextBox.Location = new Point(30, 50);
                newTextBox.Text = "Hello World!";
            }
            else
            {
                newTextBox.Location = new Point(lastOldTextBox.Location.X, lastOldTextBox.Location.Y + 30);
                newTextBox.Text = $"Hello World! ({TextBoxes.Count})";
            }
            TextBoxes.Add(newTextBox);
            this.Controls.Add(newTextBox);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = 0;
            string textBoxesDesc = string.Concat("[[", string.Join("],\n[", TextBoxes.Select(x => $"TextBox{i++}:{x.Text}")), "]]");

            File.WriteAllText(@".....\textBoxes.txt", textBoxesDesc);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: процесс]

[image: текст]

Comment: Исправил запись текста. $"TextBox{i}  -->   $"TextBox{i++}

Comment: Мне так кажется, что можно было бы отказаться от `List<TextBox> TextBoxes` совсем, так как форма уже содержит коллекцию дочерних контролов и с пом. `.OfType<TextBox>()` их всегда можно получить.

Comment: Да, можно просто найти эти контролы на форме. Но придется искать еще каждый раз последний для взятия его координат и перезаписи файлов.

Comment: `.OfType<TextBox>().Last()` и все, разве нет?

Comment: Да, посмотрел. Тогда для вывод в список надо будет просто взять N последних.