# WPF чат. Не получается выводить входящие сообщения в StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, stackpanel

Не получается выводить входящие сообщения в StackPanel. Есть одна главная форма с Frame и WPF страница. На странице реализовал то, как сообщение должно выводиться (ConclusionRightBubble()), в форме реализовал постоянный прием сообщений (ReceiveMessage())

Код вывода сообщений на самой странице (Chat):

```
public void ConclusionRightBubble(string message)  //Правый пузырь
    {
        Style BubRight = FindResource("BubbleRightStyle") as Style;
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            sp.Children.Add(new ContentControl { Content = message, Style = BubRight });
        });
    }
```

Код приема сообщений:

```
public void ReceiveMessage()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[64]; // буфер для получаемых данных
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                int bytes = 0;
                do
                {
                    bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                }
                while (stream.DataAvailable);

                string message = builder.ToString();

                Chat.ConclusionRightBubble(message); // выдает ошибку 
            }
            catch
            {
                Disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
```

Пробовал через `Chat chat = new Chat()`, пытался искать какие-то обходные пути, в итоге ничего...
Цикл точно работает, не получается именно вывести на экран это сообщение (с bindig работать не умею)

Comment: Зачем нам XAML, верно? Пусть все будет в одном месте, в C# коде навалено, а то понапридумают каких-то там XAML, Binding, да и всякие MVVM подходы, жуть! Лучше уж по старинке. Только вот вы что-то мелочитесь, моглиб и `FindResource("BubbleRightStyle")` перенести в C#, чтоб наверняка.

Comment: Не понятно что конкретно у вас не работает, данные вообще приходят? Цикл запускается? Точку останова перед и в do-while ставили? А в sp.Children.Add? Вручную без приёма сообщений ContentControl пытались добавить?

Comment: [тыц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1248356/373567) + [тыц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219057/373567) = готовый WPF чат