# Не добавляется элемент из combobox в datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Я засунул в кнопку события click:

```
cs.Add(new Class1(combobox.selecteditem.ToString(),convert.Tostring32(textbox.Text)));
datagrid.ItemSource=cs;
```

У меня добавляется только textbox а выбранный элемент combo box не добавляется и ячейка в гриде пустая

Comment: cs это что такое?

Comment: Во-первых этот код даже не скомпилруется, потому что в нем куча синтаксических ошибок,  во-вторых в WPF вообще такой код не пишут. Есть же привязки данных. Вот, смотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219057/373567, с DataGrid это работает точно так же.