# Возникает странный баг в C# winforms, связанный со скролом

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

Я создаю чат, в котором у меня есть `Panel`, внутри которого находятся сообщения в виде другой `Panel`, на которой текст самого сообщения, имя и дата отправки. С каждым новым сообщением в переменную `y_position_next_message` добавляются высота прошлого сообщения и отступ для следующего.

В общем, у меня возник необычный баг связанный с этим. Как только список моих сообщений выходит за границу `Panel`, и появляется скролл, следующее сообщение делает огромный отступ без причины, при этом переменная `y_position_next_message` хранит правильные данные, как и должно быть, но виджет себя ведет совсем по-другому. Я заметил одну закономерность: если я не буду трогать скролл, а просто буду писать новые сообщения, баг не возникнет, но, как только я проскролю до последнего сообщения, следующее опять сделает прыжок. В общем, я в полном замешательстве, код функции создания сообщения ниже.

```cs
public int DrawMessage(Message message)
    {
        Panel MessageBlock = new Panel()
        {
            Location = new Point(x_position_message, y_position_next_message),
            BackColor = block_color,
            AutoSize = true,
            MaximumSize = new Size(width, 2110),
            
        };

     

        Label name = new Label()
        {
            Text = message.name_user,
            AutoSize = true,
            ForeColor = name_user_color,
            Font = font_name
        };


        Label text = new Label()
        {
            Text = message.message_text,
            AutoSize = true,
            MaximumSize = new Size(200, 2000),
            Font = font_message,
            Location = new Point(0, 30),
            BackColor = Color.Red
           
        };

        Label date = new Label()
        {
            Text = message.data_send,
            AutoSize = true,
            Font = date_font,
            Location = new Point(10, text.Height + 50)
        };

        MessageBlock.Controls.Add(name);
        MessageBlock.Controls.Add(text);
        MessageBlock.Controls.Add(date);
        MessageBox.Controls.Add(MessageBlock);

        Debug.WriteLine("Y:" + y_position_next_message + "/X: " + x_position_message + "fort: " + MessageBlock.Height + indent_y);
        return MessageBlock.Height + indent_y;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Простите заранее если я что-то не так сделал, я первый раз тут задаю вопрос.

Comment: Всё просто, вам не нужно лепить костыли с ручным позиционированием контролов. Используйте вместо `Panel` - `FlowLayoutPanel`. Она сама поставит блоки друг за другом как надо. То есть `Location` вообще трогать не надо. Кстати сам блок может быть тоже `FlowLayoutPanel` или `TableLayoutPanel`. В общем, познакомьтесь с нормальными панелями, и вопрос решится сам собой.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно баги пропали, вроде бы во всем разобрался, только не пойму как задать FlowDirection правильно, в обычном режиме отрисовка начинается с левого угла, но мне нужно иногда рисовать и с правого и с левого.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.flowdirection

Comment: В WPF это делается [легко](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219057/373567), а вот как в винформах - не знаю. Предполагаю, что это не через FlowDirection стоит делать, а через Dock или каким-то другим образом. Например через трехколоночный TableLayoutPanel, где средняя колонка 100%, остальные авто, а потом по условию решать, куда вставить блок, в первую или третью колонку.