# Добавление нового объекта TextBox после прокрутки формы

Tags: c#, winforms

При нажатии на button добавляется новый textBox по заданным координатам, но проблема в том, что координаты не учитывают прокрутки формы. То есть если я прокручу форму немного вниз и нажму на кнопку добавления textBox, то он появится не там, где нужно. В форме свойство AutoScroll=true

```
int i = 0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            i++;
            TextBox tb;
            tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Location = new Point(100, 100 + i * 30);
            tb.Name = "textBox" + i.ToString();
            tb.Size = new Size(75, 23);
            Controls.Add(tb);

        }
```

Можно ли как-то использовать "глобальные" координаты формы, которые учитывают прокрутку формы? Или можно как-то учитывать скроллинг(узнать, насколько я прокрутил вниз относительно начала формы)?

Comment: Учитесь пользоваться `FlowLayoutPanel` и `TableLayoutPanel`, а не вот это вот всё. Похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1515969/373567

Comment: @aepot ого, не знал про такие удобные штучки, спасибо большое

Comment: `tb.Location = new Point(100, 100 + i * 30 + AutoScrollPosition.Y);`