# Адаптивность блока сообщения. WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xaml, адаптивность

Всем привет! Разрабатываю свой чат на сокетах.
Наверстал красивый интерфейс и столкнулся с проблемой адаптивности группы элементов составляющих целое сообщение или блок сообщения.
Вот как это выглядит:[image: нормальное состояние]

После расширения соседней колонки:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Xaml блока сообщения:

```
<Border Background="#FF191C21" Margin="0.5, 0,0.5,0">
                        <ListView Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedChat.Messages}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Border CornerRadius="15" Background="#FF3D4A5D">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock Margin="15,8,15,8" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,3" Foreground="#FFB8C0C3" Text="{Binding CreateDate, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToDateConverter}}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </Border>
```

Comment: ещё не могу никак убрать скролбар снизу... у кого его отключить??

Comment: отключил.......

Comment: `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` у `ListView`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ когда делаешь `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` то он просто расплывается по всей колонке

Comment: А вам что нужно? Я как понял, вам надо убрать скролл, и чтоб текст переходил автоматом на новую строку. Как это сделать, я вам сказал. Если не нужно растягивание на всю длину, то не ставьте тогда это свойство.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь. Но мне нужно, чтобы строки переносились. Они не переносятся. Strech - растягивает Border до границы колонки и получается большая синяя колбаска ;D.

Comment: MaxWidth можно задать ещё

Comment: @aepot, хорошая идея, она пришла ко мне сразу после написания этого вопроса. Может есть какой-нибудь более удобный способ создания такого блока сообщения?

Comment: Яб наверно не говорил просто так, без проверок, верно? Вот беру прям ваш XAML, вставляю в голый WPF проект, убираю прокрутку, получаю [перенос строк](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JU7Wj.png), готово. Если у вас так не работает, то значит в проекте есть что-то еще, что меняет это поведение, делайте тогда минимальный, самодостаточный пример, который можно воспроизвести у себя. Пока я не понимаю, что вы хотите, ибо просите перенос, я вам даю его, вы говорите условно "не то, мне нужен перенос"...

Comment: Кстати, вы под время отдали половину колонки, задайте последнему `ColumnDefinition` свойство `Width="Auto"`, будет тогда уже [такое](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SoSH.png). Если не нужно, чтоб до правого края касалось, то задайте отступ самому верхнему объекту (у вас это `Border`), например, на такой `Margin="0 0 15 0"` (15 пунктов с правой стороны), будет уже тогда [такое](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovNXv.png).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219057/373567