Как реализовать кастомную группировку в ListBox?
Есть ли возможность реализовать "кастомную" группировку для ListBox без использования CollectionView и CollectionViewSource?
У меня есть простая реализация MVVM с коллекцией, в которую загружаются сгруппированные объекты. Также для работы с коллекциями использовал DynamicData.
Ниже приведён весь код приложения.
ChatMessage.cs:
public class ChatMessage
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long Sender { get; set; }
    public long Receiver { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public bool Read { get; set; }
    public bool Delivered { get; set; }
}

MainWindow.xaml:
<Window
    x:Class="DynamicDataTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DynamicDataTest"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ChatViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedMessages}">
            <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock
                                Margin="0,10,0,5"
                                FontSize="14"
                                FontWeight="Bold"
                                Text="{Binding Key, StringFormat={}{0:dd MMMM yyyy}}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Content}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>

ChatViewModel.cs:
public class ChatViewModel : AbstractNotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly SourceCache<ChatMessage, long> _sourceList = new SourceCache<ChatMessage, long>(m => m.Id);

    public ObservableCollectionExtended<GroupAdapter> GroupedMessages { get; }

    public ChatViewModel()
    {
        // Load test messages
        GetTestMessages();  

        _sourceList
            .Connect()
            .Group(msg => msg.Timestamp.Date)
            .Transform(group => new GroupAdapter(group))
            .Bind(GroupedMessages)
            .Subscribe();
    }

    private void GetTestMessages()
    {
        var messages = new[]
        {
            new ChatMessage { Id = 1, Sender = 1, Receiver = 2, Content = "Hi!", Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) },
            new ChatMessage { Id = 2, Sender = 2, Receiver = 1, Content = "Hi, how are you ?", Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3).AddHours(1) },
            new ChatMessage { Id = 3, Sender = 1, Receiver = 2, Content = "I'm fine!", Timestamp = DateTime.Now },
            new ChatMessage { Id = 4, Sender = 2, Receiver = 1, Content = "Nice!", Timestamp = DateTime.Now },
        };

        foreach (var message in messages)
            _sourceList.AddOrUpdate(message);
    }
}

GroupAdapter.cs:
public class GroupAdapter : IGrouping<DateTime, ChatMessage>
{
    private readonly IGroup<ChatMessage, long, DateTime> _group;

    public GroupAdapter(IGroup<ChatMessage, long, DateTime> group)
    {
        _group = group;
    }

    public DateTime Key => _group.Key;

    public IEnumerator<ChatMessage> GetEnumerator() => _group.Cache.Items.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}


В связи с проблемой утечки памяти при использовании CollectionView возник вопрос:
Есть ли возможность реализовать "кастомную" группировку для ListBox?
Как видно выше, я реализовал интерфейс IGrouping в GroupAdapter в надежде, что это поможет, однако столкнулся с проблемами:

Заголовок группы не отображается.
Если несколько объектов относятся к одной группе, то отображается только первый.


Что я делаю не так? Буду признателен за любую помощь.

В чём смысл группировки то? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219057/373567 К тому же два вызова DateTime.Now дадут разное время даже если вы вызвали их рядом. То есть время у вас в 3 и 4 сообщении разное.

@aepot для группировки сообщений по дате(без учета времени) и отображения этого в UI как здесь Пример.

Если вы не хотите идти стандартным путем, то используйте нестандартный. Разделите сообщение на типы (входящий/исходящий), а также, как один из "типов" сделайте тип "дата". Ну и далее заполняйте коллекцию объектов отсортированных по дате (["01.10", "Вася: Привет!", "Петя: Ага", "03.10", "Вася: Ей, ты тут?"] (упрощенный вид) ), ну и дальше выводите в XAML все с нужным видом, да и как бы все, вообще без группировок будет, чисто список сообщений, между которыми будет "объект дата".

@EvgeniyZ, такой вариант решения задачи приходил мне в голову, однако к сожалению он не подходит. В дальнейшем при работе приложения должна быть возможность выбора отдельной группы.

И почему это проблема? Нажали на "Дату", выделили все сообщения, которые за эту дату, готово. Проблем не вижу.

@EvgeniyZ Спасибо за предложение, но такой подход, к сожалению, не решает всех задач. В нашей архитектуре группировка используется не только для отображения, но и для выполнения ряда операций, таких как фильтрация и манипуляции с группами сообщений. Простое добавление дат как элементов списка усложнит логику выборки и управления группами. Да и сам вопрос состоит не в том, как обойти группировку стороной создавая "велосипед", а как использовать имеющиеся механизмы для корректной работы того, что у же реализовано в .NET Framework

Так вы отказываетесь от стандартного механизма, а значит и должны придумать свой "велосипед". Именно это вы и просите от нас....

@EvgeniyZ Возможно я просто не достаточно корректно описал что необходимо. Наоборот, я не отказываюсь от стандартных механизмов, а стремлюсь использовать их по максимуму. Моя задача — не изобретение 'велосипеда', а корректная реализация группировки на основе стандартных инструментов .NET, таких как IGrouping. Смысл в том, чтобы воспользоваться готовыми возможностями платформы, не усложняя логику ручной группировкой и выборкой.
Причину отказа от CollectionView я написал выше, к сожалению этой проблемы пока никак не избежать.

@EvgeniyZ кстатить только что заметил что потерял кусок кода GroupAdapter

"этой проблемы пока никак не избежать" - ну о чем и речь, вы не хотите использовать стандартный механизм из-за того, что он имеет проблемы, ищите альтернативы. Ну а альтернативы - это изобретать свои "велосипеды", увы и ах. Нет CollectionView, нет стандартных группировок. Повторю, изобретайте свои велосипеды. Да хоть создайте объект "группа", в которой будет заголовок и коллекция с элементами, заполняйте, выводите ее, будет аналог стандартной группировки. Но опять-же, без CollectionView вам остается только разрабатывать свой велосипед.

Удалось разобраться?
